# React Scope issue. Trouble rendering view in App.js from imported file

Tags: reactjs, import, components, render

Basically I am just importing components to "build" the page.  What I am trying to do is get the functionality in my `<SideNav />` to affect the `{renderCurrentView()}` in my `App.js`.  Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong, and what the correct scope for the function export / import is?

**App.js**

```
import Header from './components/Header.js';
import SideNav from './components/SideNav.js';
import Footer from './components/Footer.js';

//  Attempted to import function Like so ..  
import { renderCurrentView } from './components/SideNav.js';

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header/>
            <SideNav/>
            <div className={"MainContainer"}>
                {renderCurrentView()}
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Main;
```

**SideNav.js**

```
import React, {lazy, useState} from 'react';

const importView = viewName =>
    lazy(() =>
        import(`../../layout/views/${viewName}`)
            .catch(() => import(`../../layout/views/Dashboard`))
    );

// If I attempt to export from here -- 
// const view from UseState hook cannot be reached
//export const renderCurrentView = () => {
//    const View = importView(view);
//    return <View/>
//};



const SideNav = () => {
    const [view, setView] = useState(null);

    const loadDashboard = () => setView('Dashboard');
    const loadInbox = () => setView('Inbox');
    const loadNewsletters = () => setView('Newsletters');

    // But I cannot export from within an export either .. 
    export const renderCurrentView = () => {
        const View = importView(view);

        return <View/>
    };

    return (
        <main>
                <button onClick={loadDashboard}> Dashboard  </button>
                <button onClick={loadInbox}> Inbox </button>
                <button onClick={loadNewsletters}> Newsletters </button>
        </main>
    );
};

export default SideNav;
```

I have tried adding:

```
import { renderCurrentView } from './components/SideNav.js';
```

To App.js and

```
export const renderCurrentView
```

But

1. I cannot export from within an export ..
2. if I move the function `renderCurrentView` outside the `SideNav()` scope, the `UseState` for constant `view` can't be reached .. I am close but no cigar!

Comment: I'm giving a hint. `renderCurrentView` is defined in `SideNav.js`, how should App.js have access to that function in the way you're calling it? Right now, it's not referenced anywhere in App.js. You might as well replace `renderCurrentView` with `imAFunctionThatDoesntExist` and you will get the same result

Comment: @Joel I have updated with further explanation of my attempts to export/import ..  I feel like I am very close, but not quite there.